# Finding a solution to a stochastic differential equation

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I tried to solve the following SDE but I'm struggling to utilize the fact that $X_1 = 0$.

Find the solution of the following differential equation:
$$dX_t=\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)X_tdt + 2t\exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right)dB_t$$
for $t \in (0,1]$ and $X_1 = 0$.

I used the ansatz: $$X_t = a(t)\left[x_0+\int_0^t b(t)dB_t\right]$$ 
and calculated the "solution": $$X_t = c_1t\exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right)(x_0+\frac{2}{c_1}B_t)$$

Is this correct so far? 
I guess the assignment was faulty and it was meant to be $X_0=0$ such that the solution simplifies to:
$$X_t=2t\exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right)B_t$$
otherwise I don't know how to proceed with $X_1 = 0$.

Comment: You should notice that the equation is not defined at $t=0$, thus it makes no sense to declare an initial condition there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $u(t)=\frac{t^2}2+\ln(t)$ then $u'(t)=t+\frac1t$ and $e^{u(t)}=t\exp(\frac{t^2}2)$ so that your differential equation reads 
$$
dX_t=u'(t)X_tdt+2e^{u(t)}dB_t\\
\\\iff\\
d(e^{-u(t)}X_t)=e^{-u(t)}(dX_t-u'X_t)=2dB_t
$$
which directly integrates to
$$
e^{-u(t)}X_t-e^{-u(1)}X_1=2(B_t-B_1)
$$
and with $X_1=0$
$$
X_t=2t\exp(\frac{t^2}{2\,})(B_t-B_1)
$$
which is not that far off from your expected general form of the solution. Note that $B_t-B_1$ is equal to $\tilde B_{t-1}$ for another Brownian motion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I still got a question. Why were you integrating from $1$ to $t$? Would that imply that I could correct my ansatz to $X_t = a(t)[x_1 + \int_1^t b(t)dB_t]$?

Comment: Yes, this is simply a time shift. Thus also $a(1)=1$.